# Trying to change axis in rpt.display() raptures

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

Hi I'm plotting timeseries like this with raptures package :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LxDc.png)

And I want to change axis of this plot into this range(2000,2022)
This is the main code:

```
start_time = 2000

    with open(f'cpd.txt') as c:
        for line in c:
            line = line[:-1].split()
            word = line[0]
            vec = []
            for v in line[1:]:
                v = float(v)
                vec.append(v)

            vec = np.array(vec)
            points = np.array(vec)
            model = "rbf"
            algo = rpt.Pelt(model=model).fit(points)
            result = algo.predict(pen=0.7)
            rpt.display(points,start_time, result, figsize=(9, 6))
            plt.title(f'{word}')
            plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95)
            plt.savefig(f'{word}_cpd')
```

The custom code is:

```
from itertools import cycle
import numpy as np
from ruptures.utils import pairwise
COLOR_CYCLE = ["#4286f4", "#f44174"]

class MatplotlibMissingError(RuntimeError):
     pass


def display(
    signal,
    start_t,
    true_chg_pts,
    computed_chg_pts=None,
    computed_chg_pts_color="k",
    computed_chg_pts_linewidth=3,
    computed_chg_pts_linestyle="--",
    computed_chg_pts_alpha=1.0,
    **kwargs
):

  try:
      import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  except ImportError:
      raise MatplotlibMissingError(
          "This feature requires the optional dependency matpotlib, you can install it 
  using `pip install matplotlib`."
      )

  if type(signal) != np.ndarray:
      # Try to get array from Pandas dataframe
      signal = signal.values

  if signal.ndim == 1:
      signal = signal.reshape(-1, 1)
  n_samples, n_features = signal.shape

  # let's set a sensible defaut size for the subplots
  matplotlib_options = {
      "figsize": (10, 2 * n_features),  # figure size
  }
  # add/update the options given by the user
  matplotlib_options.update(kwargs)

  # create plots
  fig, axarr = plt.subplots(n_features, sharex=True, **matplotlib_options)
  if n_features == 1:
      axarr = [axarr]

  for axe, sig in zip(axarr, signal.T):
      color_cycle = cycle(COLOR_CYCLE)
      # plot s
      axe.plot(range(start_t,start_t+n_samples), sig)

      # color each (true) regime
      bkps = [0] + sorted(true_chg_pts)
      alpha = 0.2  # transparency of the colored background

      for (start, end), col in zip(pairwise(bkps), color_cycle):
          axe.axvspan(max(start_t, start - 0.5), end - 0.5, facecolor=col, alpha=alpha)
      # vertical lines to mark the computed_chg_pts
      if computed_chg_pts is not None:
          for bkp in computed_chg_pts:
              if bkp != 0 and bkp < n_samples:
                  axe.axvline(
                      x=bkp - 0.5,
                      color=computed_chg_pts_color,
                      linewidth=computed_chg_pts_linewidth,
                      linestyle=computed_chg_pts_linestyle,
                      alpha=computed_chg_pts_alpha,
                  )

  fig.tight_layout()

  return fig, axarr
```

I modified 0 as start with start_t=2000, the result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnpeK.png)

I tried to use a solution found in another related topic like this, but it didn't work.